# How to manage sharded microcervice local storage?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, microservices, partitioning, event-driven

Let's assume there is a single consumer group (from kafka perspective). Consumer group consists of 20 replicas of Service instances. All work is balanced among those 20 instances based on some property (UUID). Each instance manages its own storage/state/read which in turn contains only data belonging to that shard only. So there are 20 separate storages, one for each replica. But what happens in case of scaling up or down those Services? How would the remaining 10 Services manage to get all that data previously belonging to other instances? I assume that each service may emit so-called "state event" (stream-table duality?) and other instance may get the responsibility of managing a new part of overall data based on such stream. But this is still a lot of work to do. Such a stream may consist of millions of items (even if compacted). There must be a more efficient way to achieve this. And what if we scale up? Group leader must now inform somehow respective instance to drop part of its data. I have read some books/posts about that matter but I couldn't find any concrete information on how this is managed.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at how Cassandra manages partitioning and replication.

Comment: Voting to close because this question is basically "how do I build a distributed database".  It's not answerable in the space of one stackoverflow answer.

Comment: Sorry about all confusion with the question. The problem is how to bring together event stream (Kafka) with storage (Cassandra) regarding partitioning. The particular consumer must get all events from a given partition and at the same time has access to the same data scope within Cassandra.

Comment: "Standby replicas are shadow copies of local state stores. Kafka Streams attempts to create the specified number of replicas per store and keep them up to date as long as there are enough instances running. Standby replicas are used to minimize the latency of task failover. A task that was previously running on a failed instance is preferred to restart on an instance that has standby replicas so that the local state store restoration process from its changelog can be minimized. " Kakfa docs - this is probably what I have been looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why this is tagged [apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka), since sharding isn't a Kafka term. In Kafka Streams, it can handle distribution of state stores across separate instances using the `KTable` API. When instances are scaled up and down, the data becomes temporarily unaccessible while the state is rebuilt. Different instances can query each other with "Interactive Queries".